# Notepad++ advanced replace function

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this line of code inside an HTML file, and I need to remove some lines from it.

```
<div class="viewpoint">
<h2>View (2)</h2><a href="./Viewpoints — 100 MOUNT ST160506.nwd_files/vp0002.jpg" title="View (2)"><img src="./Viewpoints — 100 MOUNT ST160506.nwd_files/vp0002.jpg"></a><span class="namevaluepair"><span class="name">Camera Position</span><span class="value">112.933ft,&nbsp;
     93.975ft,&nbsp;
     145.095ft</span></span><div class="comments">
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="comment">
<h4>Comment 2</h4><span class="namevaluepair"><span class="name">Status</span><span class="value">New</span></span><span class="namevaluepair"><span class="name">User</span><span class="value">User1</span></span><span class="namevaluepair"><span class="name">Text</span><span class="value">Grid G4 - Level B5</span></span>2016/5/9&nbsp;
  0:45:10</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>ARC and STR to coordinate slab edge and raft profile<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Anything after

```
</a>
```

should be removed up to word "Grid...."

I tried different methods with no avail.

[image]

Also, the above code repeats itself many times for each image (i.e vp0001.jpg, vp0002.jpg, etc.)

Comment: Can you clearly show an example text along with what the replacement should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Find what: `</a>.+?Grid`
Replace with: `</a> Grid`

Search Mode: `Regular expression`, `. matches newline`

[image]

This gave the output of

```
<div class="viewpoint">
<h2>View (2)</h2><a href="./Viewpoints — 100 MOUNT ST160506.nwd_files/vp0002.jpg" title="View (2)"><img src="./Viewpoints — 100 MOUNT ST160506.nwd_files/vp0002.jpg"></a> Grid G4 - Level B5</span></span>2016/5/9&nbsp;
  0:45:10</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>ARC and STR to coordinate slab edge and raft profile<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```